# htaccess rewrite sub sub domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain for a client that required the name to be like: http://x.y.com.

If a user types http://www.y.com he is redirected via htaccess to http://x.y.com. This works :)

The same client requests to also be able to enter the url like: http://www.x.y.com and also be taken to http://x.y.com...

- Is this possible?
- Am I making sense? :D

TIA!
S.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. The first thing you need is to make sure that `www.x.example.com` is defined in the DNS, and points to your server.

You also need to make sure that domain is recognised by your web server like `www.example.com` and `x.example.com` (depends on the configuration, but in Apache that would be in ServerName or ServerAlias if you are using VirtualHosts).

Then you apply the same kind of rules you applied to redirect `www.example.com` to `x.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both requirements in single rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(x\.)?y\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://x.y.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```